# hook custom win form to Outlook inspector window c#

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I am in a situation where i need to give a popup on New mail inspector window (compose/reply/forward/replyall) whenever user attaches a file I need to popup a window which is happening as of now and I am able to show my form.
Right now the position of the form is my concern. I managed to write manual adjustment code on Form load event to position it at desired location. But it is only for the case when user opens Compose mail window in Maximize mode. If user manually resize the mail window or move it somewhere the form is messing completely and it is obvious as it is not hooked to parent.

This is the code written on Form initialize event:

```
InitializeComponent();
            this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
            Outlook.Application oApplication = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
            Outlook.Inspector inspector = oApplication.ActiveInspector();
            try
            {
                //Get current inspector window

                Utility.Top = inspector.Top;
                Utility.Left = inspector.Left;
                Utility.Width = inspector.Width - 270;
                Utility.Height = inspector.Height / 2;
                this.Location = new Point(Utility.Width, Utility.Height - 110);
```

Please help

Comment: So you are essentially trying to cover up the inspector? That does not sound like a viable or particularly beautiful solution. Why not add your own Form Region to the form?

Comment: Hi Dmitry I am sorry but I am not good in form region. What i want is a popup on attachment Add event where I want to get confirmation from user to add attachment. The confirmation popup window I want to put exactly in-front of  Attachment Box in the Inspector window and want to hook it with so whatever size of the inspector my window will move along with. Hope it gives clarity over the requirement please

Comment: Cast the Inspector object to IOleWindow and call IOleWindow.GetWindow. You can then use the returned HWND for the various Windows PAI function to query the size and position of the inspector.